# Jquery alert if empty form field by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, is-empty

Here's the story.  I have a form that is being generated dynamically so I can not add to the existing code, but I need to just pop up a simple alert if the form field is left blank.

Here's the HTML:

```
 <form action="contact-us-a-big-map-version" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="widget_address" id="address_input_slpw_adv" placeholder="City/Zip">
 <input type="hidden" name="radius" value="700">
 <input type="hidden" name value>
 <a class="g1-button g1-button--solid g1-button--small">
  <span>
   <span>Go!</span>
  </span>
 </a>
 <input type="submit" value="Go!" style="display: none;"> 
</form>
```

As you can see there are no ID's or names applied to the form. Nor do I have any control over the code to add to it.

The Jquery I'm trying to use looks like this:

```
<script>
$('form').submit(function () {

var name = $.trim($('#address_input_slpw_adv').val());

// Check if empty of not
if (name === '') {
    alert('You must enter a zip code or city name.');
    return false;
}
});
</script>
```

I feel like this script should be working... am I missing something?  What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what does it do now? try to describe its current behavior because i can't see anything wrong with what you have now. also you can obtain more information about what happens, by putting debugger breaks. (use the debugger; statement). I think your submit function isn't even called?

Comment: Encpaulate your form submit function in `$(function(){ // your code });` seems like the form element is not rendered at script execution and therefore the DOM event never bound. [$(function(){ is shorthand for .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this:

**HTML EXAMPLE**

```
<form action="contact-us-a-big-map-version" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="widget_address" id="address_input_slpw_adv" placeholder="City/Zip">
    <input type="hidden" name="radius" value="700">
    <a class="g1-button g1-button--solid g1-button--small"> <span>
   <span>Go!</span>
</span>
    </a>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" style="display: block;">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
    var name = $('#address_input_slpw_adv').val();
    if (!name.trim()) {
        alert('You must enter a zip code or city name.');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Proceed with submit');
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xY97e/2/)**

As the form is dynamically generated you have to attached the event listener to either a `class`, as they are the only global event listener that work with  dynamically generated content, or the `document`, and as you do not have access to modify the `form` the document is the best place to attach it.